# React: Fix missing dependency warning useEffect with Refs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a functional component where if I have some error calling an API I want to open a Modal showing that error. The property who decides if this modal is open is stored using context API.
So I had this code in the component:

```
  const modalContext = useContext(ModalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== "") {
      modalContext.showModal();
    }
  }, [error]);
```

But I have this warning:

> *React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'modalContext'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

I read that to fix this issue I can use refs, so I changed the code and now I have:

```
  const modalContextRef = React.useRef(false);
  modalContextRef.current = useContext(ModalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== "") {
      modalContextRef.current.showModal();
    }
  }, [error]);
```

I wonder if this is the correct way to proceed or if it's a bad practice.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends what `showModal` is and if it can have a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: showModal is a function that changes the boolean value of "isModalOpen". That's the variable that I save in the context API. 
I wanted to use context API to see how it works with this example of having a modal and not passing the variable "isModalOpen" in several components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following will work for you:

```js
const ModalContext = React.createContext();
const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(
    false
  );
  //show modal never changes because using useCallback
  const showModal = React.useCallback(
    () => setIsModalOpen(true),
    []
  );
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider
      value={{
        isModalOpen,
        showModal,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};
const Modal = () => {
  const { isModalOpen } = React.useContext(ModalContext);
  return isModalOpen ? 'modal shows' : null;
};
const App = () => {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
  const { showModal } = React.useContext(ModalContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== '') {
      showModal();
    }
  }, [error, showModal]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setError('error')}>
        set error
      </button>
      <Modal />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ModalProvider>
    <App />
  </ModalProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works!

It helped me to reestructuring my code in a more efficent way and with those callbacks dont't need to set the dependency "modalContext", only the function "showModal". 
Thanks to that, when I hide the modal, React doesn't execute the useEffect showing the modal again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add modalContext to its dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (error !== "") {
    modalContext.showModal();
  }
}, [error, modalContext]);
```

Comment: Sure it should. Give it a try

Comment: is this right? `modalContext .showModal();` there is an space between `modalContex` and `.showModal();`

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typographic error. I will correct that.

Comment: That ends with a loop, cause I show the Modal and then I click in the close button's modal, but react detects the change in that dependency and execute that code in useEffect showing the modal again when the user closes it.

Comment: Oh. That's because I didn't see your full code Encarna. You can just set an additional state to control when the modal has been shown and has error.